# Oracle: INSERT on condition from other table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a SQL query where I need to insert a new sets of records based but 1 column is needed from required table.

E.g.,

```
TABLE_1
=======
ID,
A,
B

TABLE2
======
ID, 
C, 
D
```

Each `ID` are identical ID column.

I have a query of this format:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (ID, A, B) VALUES (???, "Yes", "What")
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_2 WHERE ID > 10)
```

This, clearly doesn't work.

My question: how do I add the `ID` value from Table 2 into Table 1 and make it runnable? This is a query that must run on Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, A, B)
SELECT ID,'YES','What' FROM TABLE_2 WHERE ID > 10
```